# Recognizing invalid dates in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I am trying to parse dirty input into postgres tables. I have a problem with a 'date' field occasionally containing non-dates such as '00000000' or '20100100'. pg refuses to accept these, and rightly so.

Is there a way to have postgres recognize invalid dates (or only valid dates, if that works better), so I can substitute a sensible default?

(I've considered building a table listing the dates I'm willing to accept, and use that in a sub-select, but that seems awfully inelegant.)

Cheers,

Jurgen

Comment: a date field cannot contain invalid dates. Do you perhaps mean a *varchar* column that contains date values?

Comment: It is, indeed, a varchar column which I try to interpret as a date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1280050&page=9

A more generic approach than the above:

```
create function safe_cast(text,anyelement) 
returns anyelement 
language plpgsql as $$ 
begin 
    $0 := $1; 
    return $0; 
    exception when others then 
        return $2; 
end; $$;
```

Used like this:

```
select safe_cast('Jan 10, 2009', '2011-01-01'::timestamp)
select safe_cast('Jan 10, 2009', null::timestamp)
```

Credited to the friendly dudes at the #postgresql irc channel. :)

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Solid answer, would love to see an lightweight solution implemented in PostgreSQL core. As mentioned by this comment multiplying transactions with proposed answer might cause performance issue in some cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374707/check-whether-string-is-a-date-postgresql#comment39570918_25374982

Answer (score 0):

You could write a pgsql function with an [exception handling block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).