# Check whether string is a date Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Is there any function in `PostgreSQL` that returns `Boolean` whether a given string is a date or not just like `ISDATE()` in MSSQL?

```
ISDATE("January 1, 2014")
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a built in one. [But you can create your own](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/006501c66a07$b8c08d60$0501a8c0@pcsistemas)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can create a function:

```
create or replace function is_date(s varchar) returns boolean as $$
begin
  perform s::date;
  return true;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
postgres=# select is_date('January 1, 2014');
 is_date
---------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select is_date('20140101');
 is_date
---------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select is_date('20140199');
 is_date
---------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Note that each `begin ... exception` block creates a subtransaction. So this can have a non-trivial performance impact. PostgreSQL really needs a generic way to invoke a datatype cast in a way that either (a) returns null instead of an exception on failure; or (b) invokes it as a test returning a boolean success/failure value.

Comment: I still needed this answer in 2018. Thanks.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6730401/5248144 for a more generic approach

Comment: I still needed this answer in 2020.  "PostgreSQL really needs a generic way to invoke a datatype cast in a way that either (a) returns null instead of an exception on failure; or (b) invokes it as a test returning a boolean success/failure value." -Craig R.  Holy heck, yes please.

Answer (score 2):

@ntalbs answer is good except in the case of `NULL` values. I don't want `is_date` to return `true` if I pass it a `NULL` value. This tweak gets around that issue:

```
create or replace function is_date(s varchar) returns boolean as $$
begin
  if s is null then
     return false;
  end if;
  perform s::date;
  return true;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked is null date.
Without creating a function, you can also. Var example = now()

```
select coalesce(extract(day from now()),'0') <> 0
```