# Varchar to timestamp PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

What i want to do, is to change my date column type from varchar to timestamp w/o timezone, and migrate all my data. This is what im doing:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN "datecol"
    TYPE timestamp without time zone USING(to_timestamp("datecol", 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone);
```

This works fine if data in datecol is in date format. But if i have some not valid data, like random strings (e.g "abc") how can i validate and check if date format is good? I want to set default value for those invalid fields.

EDIT: Thanks Ludvig, i solved my problem:

```
create or replace function is_date(s varchar) returns boolean as $$
begin
perform s::date;
return true;
exception when others then
return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN "datecol"
TYPE timestamp without time zone USING(
CASE WHEN is_date("datecol") = true
THEN to_timestamp("datecol", 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone
ELSE '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
END
);
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374707/check-whether-string-is-a-date-postgresql) might be of help to you.

Comment: `date format is good` Which  date formats are good? only like this: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`?

Comment: No, to_timestamp identifies formats like: YYYY, YYYY-MM, YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD, YYYY.MM.DD etc. For those formats it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter type for column with `try/catch` logic, so you either have to regexp all possible formats or you can:

1. add column "ts" of timestamp data type
2. add column "exc" boolean
3. ```
   do $$ 
     declare _r record; 
   begin 
     for _r in (select * from mytable) loop 
       update mytable set "ts" = to_timestamp("datecol", 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
       where ...PK..=_r.PK; 
     when others 
       then update mytable set "exc" = true; 
    end loop; end; $$;
   ```
4. drop datecol, rename "ts" to "datecol"
5. deal with values where "exc"

The big minus would be changed order of columns in mytable. So poor apology that you can after `create table tt as select NEEDED order from mytable; drop table mytable;alter table tt rename to mytable`, but then you will have to rebuild all references and dependants as well of course. Or even more exotic way - you can start adding column in needed order, dropping renaming until you get the old set...

Comment: Thanks, but changed order is not really what i need :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing for a valid date I would create a function that tries casting using different formats and returns the default date in case none of them work:

```
create or replace function convert_date(s varchar) 
   returns timestamp 
as 
$$
begin
  -- test standard ISO format
  begin
    return to_timestamp(s, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  exception when others then
      -- ignore
  end;

  begin
    return to_timestamp(s, 'yyyy.mm.dd');
  exception when others then
    -- ignore
  end;

  begin
    return to_timestamp(s, 'yyyy/mm/dd');
  exception when others then
    -- ignore
  end;

  begin
    return to_timestamp(s, 'yyyy-mm');
  exception when others then
    -- ignore
  end;


  begin
    return to_timestamp(s, 'yyyy');
  exception when others then
    -- ignore
  end;

  return timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then use:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
    ALTER COLUMN "datecol" TYPE timestamp without time zone 
    USING (convert_date(datecol));
```

This won't be very efficient, but for a one-time job it should work