# Delete values that are not date

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a column that can hold any value and I want to keep only values that are in a timestamp format, I tried with regex in like clause but it didn't work.

Comment: alter the columns datatype ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to `select` only those which have a timestamp? Or you want to `delete` anything which is not a timestamp? What is your timestamp format? Would you show us what you tried, please?

Comment: What regex and query did you try?

Comment: @Schwern I want to delete anything which is not a timestamp? I tried with regex in like clause as following '30-Dec-83' ~ '^(([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2}$' but that's not suitable for me

Comment: @VynlJunkie in order to change datatype of the column I need to delete values that are not timestamp that's why I am asking to avoid casting issues

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374707/check-whether-string-is-a-date-postgresql) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756432/varchar-to-timestamp-postgresql)