# Update PSQL Column with Default Date if erroneus date

Tags: sql, date, postgresql-9.3

I am using `PostgreSQL 9.3` i have a column called appointment date in a table appointment which has erroneous dates like `21117-03-04` i wish to update all rows in the column to have a default date e.g. `1900-01-01` if the value on that column is any erroneous date. I have not yet tried any solution yet. please help.

Comment: Related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374707/check-whether-string-is-a-date-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

you can use below procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MAKE_ACCURATE_DATE`()
BEGIN
DECLARE VAR_ID varchar(100);
DECLARE VAR_DATE DATE;
DECLARE VAR_FINISHED INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE DATABASE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT DATE(DATE_COLUMN) DATE_COLUMN,ID
                FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME;


                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET VAR_FINISHED = 1;

                OPEN DATABASE_CURSOR;
                GET_NEXTRECORD: LOOP

                        FETCH DATABASE_CURSOR INTO VAR_DATE,VAR_ID;

                           IF VAR_FINISHED = 1 THEN 
                        LEAVE GET_NEXTRECORD;
                        END IF;

                            IF VAR_DATE =NULL THEN
                            UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET DATE_COLUMN='1900-01-01' WHERE ID=VAR_ID;
                            END IF;

                END LOOP GET_NEXTRECORD;

                CLOSE DATABASE_CURSOR;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**OR**
**FOR POSTGRES**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_VALID_DATE(S VARCHAR) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM S::DATE;
  RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RETURN FALSE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And make change in above function as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MAKE_ACCURATE_DATE()
RETURNS void AS 

$BODY$

DECLARE

RECORD RECORD;
COUNT INT;

    BEGIN

    COUNT=0;
    FOR RECORD IN SELECT * FROM cpad.dtl_patientappointment;

    LOOP 

        IF(!IS_VALID_DATE(RECORD.appointmentdate))  THEN
        UPDATE cpad.dtl_patientappointment SET appointmentdate='1900-01-01' WHERE patientappointmentid=RECORD.patientappointmentid;
        END IF;


    END LOOP;

    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And execute this line

```
SELECT MAKE_ACCURATE_DATE();
```

It will fetch your record from table one by one and as 
`DATE(DATE_COLUMN)` is there,it will returns null if date is not proper.So after applying condition it will update that record with specific `ID`.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: my table looks like this `SELECT patientappointmentid, interactionid, appointmentdate, appointmentreasonid, 
       appointmentcomment, createdate, updatedate, deleteflag, userid, 
       providerid, deletereason
  FROM cpad.dtl_patientappointment;` please update the cursor