# ISDATE() equivalent function in greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I am converting ms SQL server queries into Postgres SQL for Greenplum database, Is there any equivalent function of ISDATE() in Greenplum/postgres?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374707/check-whether-string-is-a-date-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, there is no such function in postgres or greenplum.

But you can create a customized function. See it below

```
    create or replace function is_date(s varchar) returns boolean as $$
begin
  perform s::date;
  return true;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

For more details, see 
[Check whether string is a date Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374707/check-whether-string-is-a-date-postgresql)